# Differentiating the function $f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{\arctan x^2}{x}, & x\ne 0\\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I an trying to find out if the function
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{\arctan (x^2)}{x}, & x\ne 0\\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}
$$
is infinitely differentiable at $x=0$ or not. I think that since
$$
\arctan x = x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{2n-1},
$$
$$
\arctan (x^2) = x^2-\frac{x^6}{3}+\frac{x^{10}}{5}-\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{4n-2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\arctan (x^2)}{x} = x-\frac{x^5}{3}+\frac{x^9}{5}-\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{4n-3},
$$
$f(x)$ is analytic and, consequently, infinitely differentiable. Is this correct?

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: Yes.  But to be infinitely correct, you should note that your deduction of the power series for f(x) is valid for 0<|x|<1 but not for x=0, as f(0) is defined separately; however the assigned value f(0) does agree with the  series at x=0, so the series is equal to f(x) whenever |x|<1.